# Close process in all pc of windows domain

Tags: domain, kill-process

How can i close a particular process in ALL domain's PC? I need this for maintenance. The domain is a Windows server 2003 domain.

As Dan suggests PSKILL works very well for this purpose but i need something to list all pc connected to my domain to create a pskill batch.

How can I do?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to script something using the [Sysinternals Suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx)

Specifically, [PsKill](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896683)

Comment: Is possibile to integrate pskill with a for loop for each computer in domain?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Powershell installed on your client with the ActiveDirectory module you could do something along the lines of the following:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Foreach ($computer in Get-ADComputer -Filter *) {
    pskill -t \\$($computer.Name) -u someuser -p somepassword process-to-kill
}
```

I haven't tested this though so it probably needs some modification of the `pskill` command/syntax.